# OBSOLETE - Add Timeline and R​‌​‌​‌e​‌visions links

Tags: script, obsolete, timeline, revisions

> ### Obsolete:  The links are dead, but the forked script in the answer(s) may still work.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Partial screenshot of additions]

### About

Add revision links, and timeline links on all questions post menus.
Intended for development features, probably useless when the feature is actually implemented.

#### License

probably CC-BY-SA

#### Download

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/97069

#### Platform

Tested only on Firefox 3.6, Google Chrome 10 dev, Opera 11
(Linux versions)

#### Contact

S.Mark - mark at my-mm dot org

#### Code

Userscript (javascript) using existing Stack Overflow jQuery

source - http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/97069

Comment: **Note**: if you have SEModifications installed, this userscript isn't needed.

Comment: Hey @Mark, FYI [possible bug](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/809/the-user-signature-box-drifting-into-the-tag-info-box/811#811).

Comment: Thanks @Lazer, I have updated my script, please install it again. (I have moved timeline link to another line.)

Comment: nice one! but now superseded by [SEModifications](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an) which adds further features

Comment: If you're still maintaining this, I'd suggest changing the ID detection to something like `id=$(this).find('a[class="short-link"]').attr("href").replace(/\/[aq]\//, "").replace(/\/\d+/, "");`. That way it works on sites where you don't have an account or aren't logged in.

Answer (score 9):

[Here's a small and simpler updated fork](https://gist.github.com/cauerego/d6382a8952663bb7753f). It adds **only the timeline** link:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Stack Exchange Timeline Link
// @namespace     stackoverflow
// @description   Add a 'timeline' link to Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow posts - based on http://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-timeline-and-revisions-links/4238#4238
// @include       http*//*stackexchange.com/*
// @include       http*//*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http*//*serverfault.com/*
// @include       http*//*superuser.com/*
// @include       http*//*askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http*//*mathoverflow.net/*
// @include       http*//*onstartups.com/*
// @include       http*//*nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http*//*seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http*//*stackapps.com/*
// @exclude       http*//chat*stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http*//chat*stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude       http*//api*stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http*//data*stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       */reputation
// @grant         none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    var start=function(){
        $(".post-menu").each(function(){
            id = $(this).find("a.short-link")[0].href.replace(/^.*\/a\//, "").replace(/\/\d+(?:#.*)?$/, "").replace(/\D+/, "");
            rlink = $("<span class='lsep'>|</span><a href='/posts/"+id+"/timeline'>timeline</a>");
            $(this).append(rlink);
        });
    };

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + start + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
})();
```

Comment: Here's a substantial update that adds support for all Stack Exchange sites, including Meta sites for the Trilogy and sites such as [ubuntu.se] which have different domain names. I've also removed the `return false;` at the end of the `start` function because answers now have their own timelines. https://gist.github.com/bwDraco/85a5806b0d0681efc596

Comment: @bwDraco thanks for the update man! I'll be editing those in my end as well. :)

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't officially support HTTPS, but it mostly works.  Your include patterns currently only match HTTP.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom so true! I thought removing `http:` might work, but that backfires too hard - looks almost every site then gets included. Looks like replacing `:` with `*` worked fine, though. Hope that's good enough!