# Does the API have a method to get the total favorite count of a question?

Tags: support, api

Like it says in the title, is the total favorite count of a question exposed anywhere via the API?  I know about [the favorites method](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users), but that looks like it will give you the specific favorites of a user, and **not** the number of times (or by who) a particular question has been favorited. Am I missing anything obvious?

("No" is a valid answer — I just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to create and pass in [a filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) that will return `favorite_count`. For example, [this query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=2138&filter=!9hnGsq)VF&site=stackapps&run=true) will return the information for [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a), including

```
"favorite_count": 18
```

Comment: [this advice](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100)