# OBSOLETE - Add Timeline and Revisions Links

Tags: script, obsolete, timeline, revisions

> ### Obsolete:  Script no longer works on any Stack Exchange site. Updated version found [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/8313/add-timeline-and-revisions-links-v2).

### Screenshot

[image: in question view]
[image: in homepage]
[image: in questions list]
[image: in mod tools]

### About

This is a simple Greasemonkey script which adds both timeline and revision links to questions and answers in many of the different question views.

Within a question view, a timeline link as added to the question and revisions links are conditionally added to all posts if they don't already have one.  The homepage and other question listing views will have them too including those listed in the mod tools pages.

Influenced by [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40617/150562) (now deleted).

#### Download

(Archived links provided as Userscripts.org is dead)

- [Userscripts Page](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/102057.html)
- [Install](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/102057.user.js)
- [Source](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/102057.html)

#### Platform

Firefox and Chrome

### Contact

Please use this page as means of contact.  This is part of a personal learning exercise using javascript so support will be limited as I have no practical experience with it.  Though I've learned a lot more with what is capable so my goal is to make this as clean and idiomatic as possible.  Feedback and improvement suggestions would be appreciated.

### Future

This will be part of a larger project which will be a collection of scripts to enhance Stack Exchange if and when I <s>figure out how</s> find the time to do it.

### Updates

August 18, 2012 - Cleaned up the code a bit and added fixes to appear on more pages. Will be making changes to add Chrome support.

August 30, 2012 - Added Chrome support.

Comment: If you just want a simple script to add a **timeline link**, here you go: http://stackapps.com/a/4238/3451

Answer (score 3):

I'll use this answer to keep track of progress such as bugs and plans.  That way it will be able to keep everyone up to date on the progress.

#### Acknowledged Bugs

- Does not work on other browsers like Chrome (WIP)

#### Future Plans

- Add support for even more question views.