# Add Timeline and Revisions Links (v2)

Tags: script, timeline, revisions

### Screenshot

[image: in question view]

### About

This is a simple Tampermonkey script which adds both timeline and revision links to questions and answers in many of the different question views.

Within a question view, a timeline link as added to the question and revisions links are conditionally added to all posts if they don't already have one.  The homepage and other question listing views will have them too including those listed in the mod tools pages.

Influenced by [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40617/150562) (now deleted).

This is version 2 of my now obsolete original [Add Timeline and Revisions Links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2371/obsolete-add-timeline-and-revisions-links) script that should work on the current stack exchange sites with cleaner source targeting Tampermonkey.

**Note:** This has reduced functionality as I haven't been able to update to the current Stack Exchange sites and restore all of the original views. Right now it only covers the question views but the others will be added in due time. I'll see if using gists alone will work instead of using the old userscripts mirrors.

#### Download

- [Gist](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyMercado/63a853d49abba832fbc14aed6c249af2/)
- [Source](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JeffreyMercado/63a853d49abba832fbc14aed6c249af2/raw/setrl.userscript.js)

#### Platform

Tested on Chrome

### Contact

Please use this page as means of contact.  This is part of a personal learning exercise using javascript so support will be limited as I have no practical experience with it.  Though I've learned a lot more with what is capable so my goal is to make this as clean and idiomatic as possible.  Feedback and improvement suggestions would be appreciated.

### Future

This will be part of a larger project which will be a collection of scripts to enhance Stack Exchange if and when I <s>figure out how</s> find the time to do it.

### Updates

- 0.1 - Added links to updated version to restore links to question views.
- 0.2 - Adding stackapps to include list, fixed post modification detection.

Comment: Neither of the install links work (FF 67.0.1, TamperMonkey). Pretty sure they're required to have the extension `.user.js` for TM to detect them

Comment: It's just a gist, so you could just copy it to a new script. If I can set a name on it, I'll make that change the next time I get a chance.