# View Post Timeline

Tags: script, timeline

Inspired by [this MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/183981/how-do-you-view-vote-history-for-a-question-or-answer-or-add-some-sort-of-vote).

This tiny userscript will add a link to the timeline for any post, just below the "favorite question" star button.

Example image:

[image: timeline button example]

This is the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Add Timeline Button
// @namespace   none
// @description Adds a "View Timeline" Button to StackOverflow
// @match       http://*.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match       http://*.onstartups.com/questions/*
// @match       http://*.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match       http://*.stackapps.com/questions/*
// @match       http://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match       http://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match       http://*.superuser.com/questions/*
// @author      csharpler
// @version     0.2
// ==/UserScript==

/*
 * Version History
 *      * 0.1 (2013-06-11): First release
 *      * 0.2 (2013-06-12): * changed includes
 *                          * improved regex
 *                          - removed unsafeWindow, replaced with function wrapper
 */

withPages_jQuery(run);

function withPages_jQuery (NAMED_FunctionToRun) {
    //--- Use named functions for clarity and debugging...
    var funcText        = NAMED_FunctionToRun.toString ();
    var funcName        = funcText.replace (/^function\s+(\w+)\s*\((.|\n|\r)+$/, "$1");
    var script          = document.createElement ("script");
    script.textContent  = funcText + "\n\n";
    script.textContent += 'jQuery(document).ready( function () {' + funcName + '(jQuery);} );';
    document.body.appendChild (script);
};

function run(){
    var uri = location.href;
    var post = location.pathname.match(/questions\/(\d+)\D/i);
    var newuri = "";
    if(post && post.length > 1){
        newuri = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/posts/" + post[1] + "/timeline";
    }
    $(".favoritecount").after("<a href='" + newuri + "'>View Timeline</a>");
}
```

Feel free to submit any bugs, feature requests and comments on the script.

This script was tested with the following settings:

- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20130520 Firefox/20.0 PaleMoon/20.1-x64
- SO and MSO pages, other SE pages will probably work (please tell me if they don't!)
- Greasemonkey 1.9

Comment: Note that there are at least 3 other userscripts that do this. There's mine, below.  There's [this one from April 2011](http://stackapps.com/q/2371/7653). And, there's [this one from Feb 2011](http://stackapps.com/q/2047/7653).

Answer (score 11):

Good idea.  There's a few minor niggles, though:

1. Don't use `unsafeWindow`, this will break in Chrome and will not even work in Firefox+Greasemonkey if the effective `@grant` changes.
2. Avoid leading `*` wildcards in `@includes`, if you can help it.  This is a big performance hit.  `@match` limits the wildcard scope and performs much better and reports the sites/security correctly on Chrome.  This gets all current SE sites:

   ```
   // @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/questions/*
   // @match       *://*.onstartups.com/questions/*
   // @match       *://*.serverfault.com/questions/*
   // @match       *://*.stackapps.com/questions/*
   // @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
   // @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
   // @match       *://*.superuser.com/questions/*
   ```
3. The regex `match` needs to be more robust, to account for all legal characters in the URL, and for anchors.
4. Use injection so that the script will work on most userscript-capable browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc.).

Here's a variant of the script I've been using. It also adds a "revisions" link since a post's history is sometimes hidden. It works on Chrome and Firefox, and should work on most other userscript-capable browsers:

#### View [the source at GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/5761948).

#### Install button: [<kbd>Install from GitHub Gist</kbd>](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/5761948/raw/Add_Timeline_Button_to_Stack_Exchange_questions.user.js)

Change log:

```
Versn  Date        Change
-----  ----------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.5    2019-08-28  Updated Metadata and Lint config for Tampermonkey changes and performance.
1.4    2019-08-28  SE renamed `short-link` to `js-share-link`.
1.3    2016-08-19  SE changed Timelines. Answers were separated out from the question timeline.
1.2    2015-07-22  Updated match list.
1.1    2014-02-07  Added revisions link. (On private copy, didn't update Gist until 2015.)
1.0    2013-06-11  Initial release to the public.
```

Comment: Old comments [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85433/discussion-on-answer-by-brock-adams-view-post-timeline).

Comment: I noticed this seems to have stopped working so I posted a small tweak as a new answer, but then noticed you have a gist with the download link. I wasn't sure what the best way was to handle it - maybe you'd be best to update your gist with the change and just delete my answer once done assuming it looks OK to you?

Comment: Thanks, @PeterJ. It looks like they changed the markup in the last day or so.  **Updated the script** and will try to remember to move it to GitHub proper on some future rainy day...

Comment: @BrockAdams: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you need to use `a[class="js-share-link js-gps-track"]` instead of `a[class="js-share-link"]` which is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed recently that this stopped working and the CSS class `short-link` needed changing to `js-share-link`, here's an update:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange: Add Timeline and Revisions links to posts
// @description Adds links to posts to always show history and links to questions to show the Timeline".
// @namespace   StackExchange
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/questions/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/questions/*
// @version     1.4
// @history     1.4 CSS class short-link needed changing to js-share-link
// @history     1.3 SE changed Timelines. Answers were separated out from the question timeline.
// @history     1.2 Updated match list
// @history     1.1 Added revisions link
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$(".post-menu").each ( function (J) {
    var jThis   = $(this);
    var href    = jThis.find ('a[class="js-share-link"]').attr ("href");
    var idMtch  = href.split (/[qa]\/(\d+)/);
    if (idMtch.length > 2) {
        var id  = idMtch[1];
        jThis.append (
            '<span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/' + id + '/revisions">revisions</a>'
        );
        jThis.append (
            '<span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/' + id + '/timeline">timeline</a>'
        );
    }
} );
$(".revcell3.vm>div").each (function () {
    //-- Looks like a timebomb...
    guid = $(this).find ("a").attr ("href").match (/\w{8} (?:-\w{4} ){3}-\w{12}/)[0];
    $(this).prepend ('<a href="#rev' + guid + '">link</a><span class="lsep">|</span>');
} );
```